# sscanf to convert to a long integer

Tags: c

Can anyone explain the output of the lines below:

```
sprintf(tempStr,"%s%2s%s",year_str,month_str,day_str);    
count=sscanf(tempStr,"%ld%s",&tempout,other);
```

It creates a numeric date, using day, month and year values.

But, how does it convert the **numeric value** to a **long integer**?

For e.g.: Can you tell me, if the **year**, **month** and **day** are **`2016`**, **`02`**, and **`08`**, then what would be the output value in **`tempout`**.

Here, is how the input is taken:

```
    char date_str[20];

    char day_str[2];
    char month_str[2];
    char year_str[2];

    time_t now;
    struct tm* current_time;

    /* get current time */
    now = time(0); 

    /* convert time to tm structure */
    current_time = localtime(&now);

    /* format day string */
    sprintf(day_str,"%02d",current_time->tm_mday);

    /* format month string */
    sprintf(month_str,"%02d",current_time->tm_mon + 1);

    /* format year string */
    sprintf(year_str,"%d",current_time->tm_year);

    /* assemble date string */
    sprintf(date_str,"%s%2s%s",year_str,month_str,day_str);
```

The output of this when I run it (using http://cpp.sh/), I get is:

> **1160208**

whereas I thought it should be:

> **20160208**.

In some other context, there is a line below, Which is also **`116`** if the year is **`2016`**:

`sprintf(year_str,"%02d",options.year - 1900);`

Here, **`date_str`** is the `tempStr` mentioned above, hence, the input is: **`1160208`**

Comment: What are the values of `year_str`, `month_str` and `day_str`? It would be easier to explain if you post a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean how? `sscanf` does it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format specifier `%ld` is for implicitly typecasting the **numeric value** to `long int`, whereas, `%d` is for `int` alone.

**Edit:**

I ran your code now, using the following data types of the variables mentioned therein:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
 char tempStr[100];
 char year_str[5];
 char month_str[3];
 char day_str[3];
 long int tempout;
 char other[100];
 int count;

 strcpy(year_str, "2016");
 strcpy(month_str ,"02");
 strcpy(day_str ,"08");

 sprintf(tempStr,"%s%2s%s",year_str,month_str,day_str);
 count=sscanf(tempStr,"%ld%s",&tempout,other);

 printf("tempStr: %s\ntempout: %ld\n", tempStr,tempout);
}
```

Then only did I understand what your concern is, the output is showing:

> tempStr: 20160208
> tempout: 20160208

Clearly, we can see that the problem here is in `sprintf` and not in `sscanf`.

The format specifier `%s%2s%s` that you have given to `sprintf` means that you want to **concatenate** the three strings, `year_str`, `month_str` and `day_str` namely, without any character (**'/'**, **space** or a **'-'**) in between them. The `2` in `%2s` only means a padding of two spaces only where it is possible.

This means that when `sscanf` will try to read a `long int` into `tempout` it will read `20160208` as one number doing rightly what it is meant to do.

You therefore have to add a character such as `space` `-` or `/` between **year**, **month** and **day** and everything will work fine:

```
sprintf(tempStr,"%s %2s %s", year_str,month_str,day_str);
```

New output now is:

> tempStr: 2016 02 08
> tempout: 2016

**Edit2:**

If you look at the [Man Page of localtime()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) you will see that the ranges of the members of the `struct tm` are:

> tm_mday
>
> The day of the month, in the range 1 to 31.
>
> tm_mon
>
> The number of months since January, in the range 0 to 11.
>
> tm_year
>
> The number of years since 1900.

Which explains the addition of `1` in `sprintf(month_str,"%02d",current_time->tm_mon + 1);` so similarly, `1900` should be added to `current_time->tm_year` for correct output:

```
sprintf(year_str,"%d",current_time->tm_year+1900);
```

Comment: Yes. but i am at loss about the logic here. Pardon my understanding of C. In my eg: can you tell me what the output would be?

Comment: OK, so I think, you need a bit more explanation than what can fit in a comment, so I am making an edit to my answer. Please have a look at that.

Comment: Hi @Ahmed. I have explained the question bit more. i can see that there is a different logic used.

Comment: This is getting messy, making another edit for trying to explain what is going on.

Comment: Also, the size of the `char` array in which you want to store a string should be at least `1` more than the expected size of the string. Because in **c style strings** a terminating character `\0` needs to be stored as the last character to indicated the end of the meaningful string.